# How to increase stylus sensitivity on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, m10, stylus

I use a basic stylus with my Android phone, but when I use it with the BQ M10, the sensitivity is really poor. Is there any way of improving this?